# Xquery Not[name()="Name"] Method and XML structure

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery

I am going to try my best to explain my issue and expected result, if you have any ideas how to improve the question leave a comment.

lets say I have an .xml document like the following;

**Test.xml**

```
<db>
    <www>
        <year >1990</year>
        <author>Daren</author>
    </www>
    <www>
        <year>1990</year>
        <author>Daren</author>  
    </www>
    <www>
        <year>1989</year>
        <author>Daren</author>
    </www>
</db>
```

db being the root, www being the roots child and some more children under www.

I want to group the records by year; I have managed to do this with the following code:

```
<publications>
{
for $x in distinct-values(/*/*/year)
let $item := /*/*[year = $x]
where $item/author =  "Daren"
return <year-Pub>{<year>{$x}</year>} {for $i in $item where $i/author = "Daren" return $i }</year-Pub>
}
</publications>
```

Which has an output of:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<publications>
   <year-Pub>
      <year>1990</year>
      <www>
         <year>1990</year>
         <author>Daren</author>
      </www>
      <www>
         <year>1990</year>
         <author>Daren</author> 
      </www>
   </year-Pub>
   <year-Pub>
      <year>1989</year>
      <www>
         <year>1989</year>
         <author>Daren</author>
      </www>
   </year-Pub>
</publications>
```

Harray! this is what I wanted the records grouped by year all intact. I then wanted to remove the `<year></year>` tags from each individual record because it displayed at the top of the grouped records. This is where the issues remains. I have devised a way to remove the record tags from each entry using `$i/*[not(name()="year")]` 
Like this:

```
<publications>
{
for $x in distinct-values(/*/*/year)
let $item := /*/*[year = $x]
where $item/author =  "Daren"
return <year-Pub>{<year>{$x}</year>} {for $i in $item where $i/author = "Daren" return $i/*[not(name()="year")] }</year-Pub>
}
</publications>
```

but the output is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<publications>
   <year-Pub>
      <year>1990</year>
      <author>Daren</author>
      <author>Daren</author>
   </year-Pub>
   <year-Pub>
      <year>1989</year>
      <author>Daren</author>
   </year-Pub>
</publications>
```

As you can see the `<www></www>` tags are gone, I can see why this is because when you write `$i/*[not(name()="year")]` you are saying go down to the next step from `$i` which would be the children of www and return those records without the `<year></year>` tags. I am just unsure how to modify my code to give the desired results which is the `<www></www>` tags included and the `<year></year>` tags removed.

Answer (score 1):

Using XQuery 3.0, you can use the `group by` expression to group your results. I have then also written a filter function for you that will strip out any descendant element of a specific name. You can use that filter function to filter out the `year` of `www` and any other elements you wish.

```
xquery version "3.0";

declare function local:filter($nodes as node()*, $names as xs:string+) {
    for $n in $nodes
    return
        typeswitch($n)
            case element() return
                if(not(local-name($n) = $names))then
                    element {node-name($n)} {
                        local:filter($n/(@*|child::node()), $names)
                    }
                else()

            default return
                $n
};

<publications>
{
    for $w in /db/www
    let $year := $w/year
    group by $year
    return
        <year-Pub>
            <year>{$year}</year>
            {
                (: add any other names you wish to
                   filter into the sequence with "year" :)

                local:filter($w, ("year"))
            }
        </year-Pub>
}</publications>
```

Answer (score 0):

Then you can just add a wrapping `<www>` around the `$i/*[not(name()="year")]` :

```
<publications>
{
for $x in distinct-values(/*/*/year)
let $item := /*/*[year = $x]
where $item/author =  "Daren"
return 
    <year-Pub>
    {<year>{$x}</year>} 
    {
        for $i in $item 
        where $i/author = "Daren" 
        return <www>{$i/*[not(name()="year")]}</www> 
    }
    </year-Pub>
}
</publications>
```

Output :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<publications>
   <year-Pub>
      <year>1990</year>
      <www>
         <author>Daren</author>
      </www>
      <www>
         <author>Daren</author>
      </www>
   </year-Pub>
   <year-Pub>
      <year>1989</year>
      <www>
         <author>Daren</author>
      </www>
   </year-Pub>
</publications>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response however this is an example of the data, I should have been more specific, <www> are not the only tags.